# Unable to Modify Application Settings when Unit Testing

Tags: c#

I am trying to change some Application Settings that live within the Settings of a Windows Service which would be set during installation. The settings I want to set for a Unit Test.

Now, the assemblyinfo file has the InternalsVisibleTo to the Unit Test Project.

In my Test Method I can go drill down to Settings.Default on the Project I want to test and I can see all the settings. However, when I go for instance:

```
   dummy.PropertyValues["MySetting"].PropertyValue = "SomeValue";
```

I get a null reference exception.

dummy is set as:

```
    var dummy = MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default;
```

Is there away I can set the Application Settings I want for a unit test?

Comment: This is why access to configuration variables should be abstracted away; you shouldn't need a web/app config or settings file for unit tests

Comment: Everyone is missing the point. The settings file is part of the project I am testing. There are values that are set when it installed. However in order to test a method in that project these settings need to be set. I want to set these values in order to complete the test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem seems to be with Visual Studio 2010.

After restarting it, and as the Unit Test already had access via assembleyInfo.cs, I was able to set the Property Setting as described in my question.

Answer (score 1):

This is something that can get anyone confused. There are two settings available in visual studio projects; one is `ProjectSettings` and other is `Application configuration settings`.

Here `MyProject.Properties.Settings.Default` is your project settings. Application settings are available under `System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.Appsettings`. So may be you want to use your dummy object for Application settings:

```
var dummy = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.Appsettings;
```

Now if you update the value it will be update the Appsettings collection in your current session:

```
dummy.PropertyValues["MySetting"].PropertyValue = "SomeValue";
```